# Web-API controller multiple GET int and string parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to have a controller with multiple GET, one for all, one with int parameter and the other with a string parameter. The following example still give me error:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
    {
        return GetStudents();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Student Get(int id)
    {
        return GetStudents().FirstOrDefault(s=> s.id == id);
    }

    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public Student Get(string name)
    {
        return GetStudents().FirstOrDefault(s=> s.name == name);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Current I get the following error

[image]

Comment: what error do you get, please specify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `int` and `string` are treated equivalently in the url so it can't differentiate between the methods. You would need to either to have an additional part of the route, for example `[HttpGet("id/{id}")]` and `[HttpGet("name/{name}")]`, or use query strings.

Alternatively you can have a single method and try parse the parameter into an `int`, if it succeeds, then retrieve by id, otherwise retrieve by name.

Comment: Only fix to this [HttpGet("id/{id}")] and [HttpGet("name/{name}")]

Answer (score 2):

One way is like all of the other community members said,you could add additional part of the route to specify them.

Another way is that you could use [Route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#route-constraint-reference):

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public Student Get(int id)
{
}

[HttpGet("{name}")]
public Student Get(string name)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your route action to this

```cs
[HttpGet("id/{id}")]
public Student Get(int id)
{
    return GetStudents().FirstOrDefault(s=> s.id == id);
}

[HttpGet("name/{name}")]
public Student Get(string name)
{
    return GetStudents().FirstOrDefault(s=> s.name == name);
}
```

Then you can call your action like this

`/Students/name/john`

`/Students/id/123`

Answer (score -2):

This is impossible since you have created ambiguous routes.
Try it like this:

```
[HttpGet("id/{id}")]
public Student Get(int id)
{
    return GetStudents().FirstOrDefault(s=> s.id == id);
}

[HttpGet("name/{name}")]
public Student Get(string name)
{
    return GetStudents().FirstOrDefault(s=> s.name == name);
}
```

Comment: It s a copy of the previous answers